# incompatible types: java.lang.String cannot be converted to int

Tags: java

```
/**
* this is from the r2j class
*/
public String getCurrentState() {
    trace("getCurrentState() starts... ...and ends with value " + currentState + ", " + STATES[currentState]);
    return currentState + ", " + STATES[currentState];
}


/**
 *  provide the identity of the specified state
 *  @return which state is of a given number
 */
public String getSpecificState(int stateNum) {
    trace("getSpecificState() starts... ...and ends with value " + stateNum + ", " + STATES[stateNum]);
    return stateNum + ", " + STATES[stateNum];
}
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. The code you've posted is incomplete

Comment: It looks like the error comes from the `R2JCD2` class, please show us this class.

Comment: where is your getCurrentState method?

Comment: The problem is probably in `bot.getSpecificState(bot.getCurrentState())`. What type does `bot.getCurrentState()` return, and what does `bot.getSpecificState()`expect?

Comment: Dont append strings like that if you can avoid it. format the string.

Comment: @Berger        
public String getCurrentState()
    {
        trace("getCurrentState() starts... ...and ends with value " + currentState + ", " + STATES[currentState]);
        return currentState + ", " + STATES[currentState];
    }
 public String getSpecificState(int stateNum)
    {
        trace("getSpecificState() starts... ...and ends with value " + stateNum + ", " + STATES[stateNum]);
        return stateNum + ", " + STATES[stateNum];
    }

Comment: thats from the r2j class @Berger sorry if it's messy

Comment: You should edit your question instead of putting this info in comments, it would be easier to read

Answer (score 2):

You call `bot.getSpecificState(bot.getCurrentState())`. `bot.getSpecificState()` expects an `int` parameter, but `bot.getCurrentState()`returns a `String`. Java complains, because the passed `String`is not compatible with the expected `int`.

Answer (score 0):

The class R2JCD2 has method getSpecificState which is probably expecting an int parameter and you seem to be passing it a string parameter, i.e. the return value of method getCurrentState of the same class. If you provide the R2JCD2 class source then we would know for sure.